# How do I access the jwt payload from .net 6 minimal api webapplication

Tags: .net

I'm trying to implement jwt in my .net 6 minimal web application... similar to what they did here:
https://dev.to/moe23/net-6-minimal-api-authentication-jwt-with-swagger-and-open-api-2chh

Everything seems to work fine but when I am in a authorized path.  How do I get access to the jwt payload.  I stored the user id in this payload and I would like to pull that information out of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run AddJwtBearer (options => {...}
set options.SaveToken=true so it looks something like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o=> {
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateLifetime = false, // In any other application other then demo this needs to be true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
    options.SaveToken=true;
});
```

Then in your endpoint handler you access the data using the http context.

```
 app.MapPost("/whoami", [Authorize] async (HttpContext http) =>
   {
       Console.WriteLine("##################");
       var iam=http.User.Claims.Where( c=>c.Type == "username").Select(c=>c.Value ).SingleOrDefault();
       Console.WriteLine(iam);
       return "all good";
   }).WithTags("Authentication");
```